# Auto fill form after selecting an item from my combo box

Tags: php, ajax, combobox, autofill

I am stuck on customerdetails.php page where customer need to select the billing address title from the combo box & the automatically the form with firstname,lastname,address,city...etc fields should get filled with the details from the customer table in database. How should i achieve that?

```
      <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <select name="address"><
                    <option value="#">Select Address...</option>
                        <?php
                            $address = getAddressTitle($customer_id);
                            $count = count($address);
                                for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
                                {
                                    extract($address[$i]);
                                    echo '<option value="'. $addressid .'">' . $addresstitle . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The above code is used for combo box values.

Answer (score 0):

IT seems that you should send ajax request after selecting billing address to server, select data from db and return result in json, fill form with your fetched data.
For ajax it's quick and simple to use library like jquery.

Comment: i dont know how to use ajax. could please help me with that?